# Matrix derivative w.r.t. a general inverse form: $(A^TA)^{-1/2}D(A^TA)^{-1/2}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-inverse, orthogonal-matrices

I want to find derivative of matrix $(A^TA)^{-1/2}D(A^TA)^{-1/2}$ w.r.t. $A_{ij}$ where D is a diagonal matrix. Alternatively, it is okay too to have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}} a^T(A^TA)^{-1/2}D(A^TA)^{-1/2}b$$

Is there any reference for such problem? I have the matrix cookbook which gives results when $D=I$. But how is this general form evaluating to?

To give more information, empirical distribution of diagonal of diagonal matrix D converges to some known distribution.

Comment: try http://www.matrixcalculus.org ...

Comment: I'm afraid it does not support square root of matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Since calculating the derivative of $B=(A^T A)^{-1}$ with respect to $A$ is familiar,
$$dB=-(A^TA)^{-1}(dA^TA+A^TdA)(A^TA)^{-1},$$
let me compute the derivatives with respect to $B$, to focus on the square root difficulties. So we seek the derivative of $X=\sqrt{B}D\sqrt{B}$ with respect to the symmetric positive definite matrix $B$. Start from
$$dX=(d\sqrt{B})D\sqrt B+\sqrt{B}D(d\sqrt{B}).$$
[Vectorize,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))
$$\text{vec}\,dX=\bigl[\sqrt{B} D\otimes I+I\otimes \sqrt{B}D\bigr]\,\text{vec}\,(d\sqrt{B}),$$
and use the [identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1320527/87355)
$$\text{vec}\,(d\sqrt{B})=(\sqrt{B}\oplus\sqrt{B})^{-1}\,\text{vec}\,dB,$$
to arrive at
$$\text{vec}\,d(\sqrt{B}D\sqrt{B})=\bigl[\sqrt{B} D\otimes I+I\otimes \sqrt{B}D\bigr]\,(\sqrt{B}\oplus\sqrt{B})^{-1}\,\text{vec}\,dB.$$
Here $\otimes$ and $\oplus$ are Kronecker products and sums.